# I only want 1 info window open - Google Maps API JS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow

I have a google map and I want the first window to open when the page loads, but my coding I have now opens ALL the windows. See JS here:

```
 var markers = [];

function initialize() {
    // Map options
    var mapOptions = {
        scrollwheel: false,
        zoom: 6,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-1.919502, 36.256042),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }
    // Create a map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    // Set locations and content
    var locations = [
        ['A', -1.919502, 36.256042, 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWM0W.png'],
        ['B', -2.079736, 34.401916, 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWM0W.png'],
        ['C', -1.246850, 35.158567, 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWM0W.png'],
        ['D', -4.696879, 36.734848, 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWM0W.png'],
        ['E', -7.972198, 32.880363, 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWM0W.png'], ];

    // Markers positions
    var marker, i;

    // For each point on the location put a marker
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map,
            icon: locations[i][3]
        });

        // Activiate markers and infowindow to open on click of a link
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
        markers.push(marker);


        // Set the first info window to appear on page load
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);

        // Create Polylines
        var trackerRouteCoordinates = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(-1.919502, 36.256042),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-2.079736, 34.401916),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-1.246850, 35.158567),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-4.696879, 36.734848),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-7.972198, 32.880363), ];

        var trackerPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: trackerRouteCoordinates,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.1,
            strokeWeight: 3
        });

        trackerPath.setMap(map);
    }
}
            // Load map on window load
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

// Create the function that triggers a click on a link to show a marker
function myClick(id) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[id], 'click');
}
```

I am completely new here and this will be a quick fix but I'm not too good at Javascript so can anyone help. See the js fiddle if you want: http://jsfiddle.net/clockingowlhours/3JfdP/23/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening infowindow every time in for loop. You need to add an `if` control to open only first infowindow. Update your code as below:

```
...
// Set the first info window to appear on page load
if(i == 0) {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
}

// Create Polylines
...
```

Comment: 100% works...as a noob I thank you. You will be forever remembered user3280126 as my first answer ever on stack

Comment: Don't underestimate yourself, we all do such things, especially you are saying that you are not good at js. Enjoy learning :)